# Singleton service visible from the classes

Tags: asp.net, blazor, blazor-client-side

I have a singleton service class

```
    public class Globals
    {

        public string serverURL { get; set; } = "";
        public string hostURL { get; set; } = "";
    }
```

and I have registered it in the Main function:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<Services.Globals>();
```

anyway I would like to access it from the rest of the Classes in the project, not only the razor pages.
For instance I have a class inside a PCL library:

```
public class MyStuff
{

    public MyStuff()
    {
       - How do I access Globals in here?!
    }

    public void MyStuffMethod()
    {
       - How do I access Globals in here?!
    }
}
```

- How to access a Singleton object from the rest classes in the project ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Access like this, you just need to add a parameter in constructor of class.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private Globals _globals;
        public HomeController(Globals globals)
        {
            _globals = globals;
        }
}
```

Comment: Well.. But how do I get the singleton Globals to the classes ?

Comment: builder.Services.AddSingleton<Services.Globals>(); you have added as singleton , so it will be singleton class. Any class you need to add Global as paramter in constructor and you will get object of global. HomeController is also a class.

Comment: Not sure I do understand. How do I access it in an example please.

Comment: private Globals _globals;
  public HomeController(Globals globals)
  {
   _globals = globals;
   test test = new test(_globals);
  }

Comment: No. I mean about the parameter of HomeController. What I am passing to the parameter ?

Comment: you do not need to pass anything to home contoller, when , dotnet DI try to resolve dependencies then it will automatically resolve this and inject a object of this class to home controller constructor

Comment: I am not even more confused. But how do I am accessing Globals as a singleton inside PCL class object ?!

Comment: @YordanY the point about Dependency Injection is that the host (ASP.NET) injects the requested service. If you have a class (e.g. `MyClass`) that needs the value, set it in the constructor.

The controller gets the service injected -> the controller action creates your class, `var tmp = new MyClass(_globals);` 

If you're not creating the class in a controller action, you need to explain where it is being used so we can guide you

Comment: Well.. I've never mention about controller anything in the original post. The singleton need to be shared between the classes in a separate client side library, and yet be presented this data to the blazor main project.